# MySQL tables not found or not displayed

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a webpage where I want to display some items updated from a database which in this case is mysql. 
The **html** for the list

```
<div id="right-column-sidebar-two">
<h3 id="header">Most</h3>
<ol>
<li><a href="#">R</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Q</a></li>
<li><a href="#">P</a></li>
<li><a href="#">O</a></li>
<li><a href="#">N</a></li>
<li><a href="#">M</a></li>
<li><a href="#">L</a></li>
<li><a href="#">K</a></li>
<li><a href="#">J</a></li>
<li><a href="#">I</a></li>
</ol>
</div>
```

These list items have been stored in my database and the combined **mysql/php/html** looks like this

```
<div id="right-column-sidebar">
<ol>
<?php
$link = mysql_connect("host", "user", "password");
mysql_select_db("db", $link);
$query = "SELECT * FROM `table_name` LIMIT 0, 30 ";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)):
?><li><a href="#"> <?php echo $row['title']; ?></a></li>
<?php endwhile;
?>
</ol>
</div>
```

Now I have two tables I want to use in this case, I tried both of them separately and in a) 
I get no error messages, but nothing is displayed and in b) i get an error message saying that the table doesnt exist.

I don't know any mysql besides the code I just provided so its hard to determine what the causes might be. Would appreciate some tips.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't use `mysql_*`, instead use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

As for your problem, from the first table, you are not getting any results because probably there is no data in the table.

In the second table you get the table not found error, since the table does not exist, meaning you got the table name wrong.

Can you access the DB with a GUI client like [SqlYog](http://code.google.com/p/sqlyog/downloads/list) or phpmyadmin?  Try running your queries in this tool and see what you get.

Comment: I am currently using phpmyadmin. And the tables do exist, and I checked the names it all is correct. I have 5 items, all are only text-based and have data type Varchar(30) Null No Standard None

Comment: did you try running: `SELECT * FROM `table_name` LIMIT 0, 30` in phpmyadmin?

Comment: I just did, and it responded with : 'MySQL returned an empty result

Comment: How can it be empty when I have items in the list?

Comment: try losing the `LIMIT`, run just: `SELECT * FROM table_name`

Comment: I tried it, still nothing. I even changed the * with an item from the table, but it still responds the same

Comment: By the way, By running you mean SQL query in the database right?

Comment: yes :). if you click the table on the left side and browse it, you see values in it?

Comment: yes when i click on a table, it return a query up top saying that the table is empty. but below it the table is listed with all the items. in the Field section i have the name, type, and so forth...

Comment: Are you seeing actual data or just the column names!?

Comment: I am not sure I know the difference appearance-wise

Comment: Column names are the columns you defined your table should have: id,name,email etc. Data is the actual data in the table:id=>1, name=> J Hove, email => example@gmail.com etc..., you are seeing the column names but there is no actual data in the table

Comment: Well i don't understand the language, but from what i do understand you made a complete mess... instead of creating the table and giving it a column called name and then assign a value to name: Assassin's Creed, you created a column and you **CALLED** it Assassins Creed.

Comment: look here, it might help you: http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/phpmysql/2

Comment: Only possible mistake is Table Name is exist.It means no table ( On that name you are providing) inside your database .

Answer (score 0):

If your phpMyAdmin no longer sees any tables in any of your local databases, that is because permissions change away from mysql.mysql on any database directory under /var/lib/mysql to, say, root.root (most probably). use this query to change the owner:

chown -R mysql.mysql /var/lib/mysql/*

tutorial via http://www.geckoandfly.com/7481/solution-for-no-tables-found-in-database-mysql-error-in-phpmyadmin/